# RemixJS: automatically revalidating fetcher.load() from other route

Tags: javascript, remix, remix.run

Considering I have 2 components on my route, this is code for problem demonstration purpose:

```
const List = () => {
    const fetcher = useFetcher();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (fetcher.type === 'init') {
            fetcher.load('/exercises/some-list-id'); // This is outside our route tree
        }
    }, [fetcher.type])
}

const RemoveFromList = () => {
    const fetcher = useFetcher();
    const removeFetcher = useFetcher();

    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
        removeFetcher.submit({
            subaction: 'removeListItem',
            id: 'some-item-id'
        }, { method: 'post' });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (removeFetcher.type === 'done') {
            // That code do not update data in <List/> component
            fetcher.load('/exercises/some-list-id');
        }
    }, [removeFetcher.type]);
}
```

Given <List/> and <RemoveFromList/>, these 2 components do not have data from `fetcher.load` in sync when I am used to have such functionality in RTK Query or Apollo Client.

I know that Remix is refetching all loaders going from root and going down on route tree:
[image]

But my fetcher loader `/exercises/some-list-id` is not refetched. I assume that because that loader is outside my loader's route tree.

Do I understand correctly that kind of fetcher **will not** be refetched and I have to think of some kind of reducer or passing functions which will reload the data?

I am trying to keep data from API in 2 separate components in sync.